# Paint chip or carbon crack

Tags: road-bike, carbon, damage

Looking at this bike to buy but I’m 3 hours away from where it is.

[image]

Not sure if it’s a paint chip or a carbon crack, I asked how it happened and he said he was carrying it upstairs with his bike pump and pump got tangled in the bike cause a trip. So is it a paint chip or carbon crack do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Even from the low resolution photo this looks much worse than a simple paint chip.

Not worth pursuing in my opinion.